# Link between variance and Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I've read that:

$$ var(r) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}(r_{t}-\bar{r})^2$$

is equal to:

$$ var(r) = \frac{1}{T^2} \sum_{k=1}^{T-1} R_{k}R_{k}^*$$

with $R_k$ the $T$-point DFT coefficients of $r_t$:

$$ R_{k}= \sum_{t=0}^{T-1}{r_t}e^{-j\frac{2\pi kt}{T}}$$

I tried to play with the formulas to match the equations, but without success. Any hint on the solution?

Comment: You need a square in the definition of variance...

Answer (score 1):

(let us assume that we work on a centered function (mean = $0$).

Nothing astonishing : the **continuous** Fourier Transform is an isometry :

$$\|{\frak FT}(r)\|=\|r\|$$

This property is known to be preserved for the (DFT) Discrete Fourier Transform (see Parseval/Plancherel theorems [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform); morever, if you observe the variance, it is defined as a sum of squares, thus is by itself a norm (in the hermitian sense) ; from there your formula follows.

(don't pay too much attention to coefficient $1/N$ ; it is possible to eliminate it into by tuning the definition of the DFT).